# Oracle SQL: SUM of 'amount_sold' rows for each client

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display for each client the total /sum/ amount (from `amount_sold`) saved as a `total_amount` field. And in `WHERE` to set that `total_amount` is greater than or equal to `cust_credit_limit` :

```
total_amount >= cust_credit_limit
```

//

```
SELECT CONCAT (CONCAT(cust_first_name,' '),cust_last_name) AS customer_name,
    amount_sold,
    (CASE WHEN cust_credit_limit<=1500 THEN 'Low limit'                   
          ELSE 'High limit'
          END) AS credit_limit_level,
    cust_valid
    FROM sh.customers JOIN sh.sales
    ON customers.cust_id = sales.cust_id
    ORDER BY customer_name ASC;
```

The results now look like this:

[image]

But I need only one row for each client with the sum of all `amount_sold` for this client AS `total_amount`

**EDIT: I tried as recommended in comments and it worked. But I have another condition - to order the results by 'upper_income_level' and when I add

```
'lpad( substr(cust_income_level, instr( cust_income_level, '-') + 2 ), 9, '0') AS upper_income_level,'
```

it appears "not a GROUP BY expression".

```
'SELECT CONCAT (CONCAT(cust_first_name,' '),cust_last_name) AS customer_name, 
lpad( substr(cust_income_level, instr( cust_income_level, '-') + 2 ), 9, '0') AS upper_income_level,

    SUM(amount_sold) as total_sold,
   

    (CASE WHEN cust_credit_limit<=1500 THEN 'Low limit'                   
          ELSE 'High limit'
          END) AS credit_limit_level,
    cust_valid
    FROM sh.customers JOIN sh.sales
    ON customers.cust_id = sales.cust_id
WHERE cust_valid = 'A' AND cust_income_level LIKE '%-%'
    GROUP BY  
      CONCAT (CONCAT(cust_first_name,' '),cust_last_name),
      cust_valid,
      cust_credit_limit

    HAVING SUM(amount_sold) >= 50*cust_credit_limit

    ORDER BY upper_income_level DESC, customer_name ASC;'
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Comment: And please don't use images, but copy and paste the table as text here. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2270762

Comment: You have edited your request, but you haven't answered my question regarding your DBMS, nor have you changed the image to text. Moreover, I highly doubt that you cannot use the desired `ORDER BY` in my query. At last: having to look for substrings indicates a suboptimal data design. It seems there should be two columns `lower_income_level` and `upper_income_level` instead of one `cust_income_level`.

Comment: As to the DBMS: The standard string concatenator is `||`. You are using nested `CONCAT` instead, so I suppose your DBMS does not support standard string concatenation, nor is its `CONCAT` function capable of dealing with more than two strings at once?

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't copy the result. I am using Oracle Live SQL. 
From 'cust_income_level' which has similar content: 'G: 130,000 - 149,999' I needed to get only 149,999 and convert it to a number ('upper_income_level') because I use it as numeric in ORDER BY.

Comment: Okay, it's Oracle then. I've applied the additional requirements to my answer. I am using `regexp_substr`, but you can just as well use a combination of `substr` and `instr`. Please notice that you wouldn't have this conversion problem, if the columns for lower and upper income would be in separate numeric columns. It would be better to change the table design accordingly rather than fight the design in every other query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query shall deal with customers and their total sale. So, select from the customers table and join the aggregated total sale:

```
select
  c.cust_first_name || ' ' || c.cust_last_name as customer_name,
  to_number
  (
    regexp_substr(c.cust_income_level , '[0123456789,]+$'),
    '999999999D999',
    'nls_numeric_characters = '',.'''
  ) as upper_income_level,
  s.total_sale,
  case when c.cust_credit_limit <= 1500 
       then 'Low limit'                   
       else 'High limit'
  end as credit_limit_level,
  c.cust_valid
from sh.customers c
join
(
  select cust_id, sum(amount_sold) as total_sale
  from sh.sales
  group by cust_id
) s on s.cust_id = c.cust_id
    and s.total_sale >= c.cust_credit_limit
where c.cust_valid = 'A' 
and c.cust_income_level like '%-%'
order by upper_income_level desc, customer_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a SUM and a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT CONCAT (CONCAT(cust_first_name,' '),cust_last_name) AS customer_name,

    SUM(amount_sold) as total_sold,

    (CASE WHEN cust_credit_limit<=1500 THEN 'Low limit'                   
          ELSE 'High limit'
          END) AS credit_limit_level,
    cust_valid
    FROM sh.customers JOIN sh.sales
    ON customers.cust_id = sales.cust_id

    GROUP BY  
      CONCAT (CONCAT(cust_first_name,' '),cust_last_name),
      cust_valid,
      cust_credit_limit

    HAVING SUM(amount_sold) >= cust_credit_limit

    ORDER BY customer_name ASC;
```

Tips:

- You might find that your concat accepts multiple parameters and concats all of them e.g. `CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)`
- Rules of GROUP BY: Anything not contained in a SUM, AVG, or similar aggregation function in your SELECT, must be in the GROUP BY. At the time GROUP BY is done, the aliases in the select list don't exist, so you must instead use the expression that prepares the result (or some child part of it such that the whole expression can be computed from grouped values)
- `HAVING` is like a where clause that is done after a group by. `WHERE` is done before a group by. `HAVING` can hence reference grouped and aggregated expressions, but they must be grouped or aggregated

Comment: add `HAVING total_sold >= cust_credit_limit`  (first line of question )

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sum(), group by and having:

```
    SELECT CONCAT (CONCAT(cust_first_name,' '),cust_last_name) AS customer_name,
    sum(amount_sold) as total_amount,
    (CASE WHEN cust_credit_limit<=1500 THEN 'Low limit'                   
          ELSE 'High limit'
          END) AS credit_limit_level,
    cust_valid
    FROM sh.customers JOIN sh.sales
    ON customers.cust_id = sales.cust_id

    GROUP BY customer_name, credit_limit_level, cust_valid
    HAVING sum(amount_sold)>=max(cust_credit_level) 
    ORDER BY customer_name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have 2 cutomer with the same name,cust_id in group by is the must.

```
SELECT customers.cust_id,
       CONCAT (CONCAT(cust_first_name,' '),cust_last_name) AS customer_name,
       sum(isnull(amount_sold,0)) amount_sold
FROM sh.customers JOIN sh.sales
    ON customers.cust_id = sales.cust_id
group by customers.cust_id,CONCAT (CONCAT(cust_first_name,' '),cust_last_name)
having sum(isnull(amount_sold,0)) >= max(cust_credit_limit)
ORDER BY customer_name ASC;
```